# How to use tor browser using selenium webdriver (java)? I have tried below code so far but getting message: 'tor failed to start'

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, tor

```
import java.io.File;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;

public class torr1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette",
                "C:\\Users\\ghorh\\Documents\\selenium-bazinga\\Drivers\\geckodriver.exe");
        String torPath = "C:\\Users\\ghorh\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\firefox.exe";
        String profilePath = "C:\\Users\\ghorh\\Desktop\\Tor Browser\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default";

        File torProfileDir = new File(profilePath);
        FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(new File(torPath));
        FirefoxProfile torProfile = new FirefoxProfile(torProfileDir);

        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.setBinary(binary);
        options.setProfile(torProfile);
        options.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
        driver.get("http://google.co.in");

    }

}
```

I have tried the above code so far but getting message: 'tor failed to start'. Could somebody please help on what changes are required for the above code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use FireFox driver. 
Try use TorBrowserDriver as specified in its readme: https://github.com/webfp/tor-browser-selenium

Or if you want to use firefox - use GeckoDriver that can be downloaded from the next link:
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0